# How to show summation function in Mathematica Instead of expand the whole series?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to compute the derivative for my homework assignment, and the homework is using a Summation series where i have shown in the first line of my code.

Mathematica expanded all terms for me in this series. I am wondering if there is a way i can make it return the result using an Epsilon sign.

```
f[x_]=Sum[k*Exp[-Subscript[a,k]*x^3],{k,1,7}]

E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 1]) + 2 E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 2]) + 
 3 E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 3]) + 4 E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 4]) + 
 5 E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 5]) + 6 E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 6]) + 
 7 E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 7])

f'[x]

-3 E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 1]) x^2 Subscript[a, 1] - 
 6 E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 2]) x^2 Subscript[a, 2] - 
 9 E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 3]) x^2 Subscript[a, 3] - 
 12 E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 4]) x^2 Subscript[a, 4] - 
 15 E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 5]) x^2 Subscript[a, 5] - 
 18 E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 6]) x^2 Subscript[a, 6] - 
 21 E^(-x^3 Subscript[a, 7]) x^2 Subscript[a, 7]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Mathematica is "an infinite evaluation system" which means that it wants to evaluate everything, perhaps over and over, until it stop changing and that means it is in what Mathematica thinks is "the simplest form." Trying to subvert this is often not easy. You can use Mathematica as a sort of clumsy word processor if you never ask it to evaluate anything and just manually type in what you want to display. You can also try to subvert this by putting the D[ expr,x ] inside your sum, not outside. Then with your mouse you scrape over the D[ ...] to highlight and press ctrl shift enter to eval that

Comment: leave  the sumation limit a symbol `k,1,n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HoldForm` to display the sum:-

```
HoldForm[Sum[k*Exp[-Subscript[a, k]*x^3], {k, 1, 7}]]
```

You can use `E` instead of `Exp` to display output as `e`.  `TraditionalForm` may further improve the appearance:-

```
HoldForm[Sum[k*E^(-Subscript[a, k]*x^3), {k, 1, 7}]] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the late response!

Comment: @Chris Degnen Can I do this in the output? For example, my input is Sum[K[i], {i, 1, 4}]-K[4], then the output will be K[1] + K[2] + K[3]. If I use Holdform in the input, the result will be Sum[K[i], {i, 1, 4}] - K[4] (in summation notation form]. The result I want is Sum[K[i], {i, 1, 3}] (in summation notation form). Thanks!